# Fill document from a google spreadsheet

Tags: forms, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a web form that populates a Google spreadsheet.

My question is can I populate a document  with some or all of the information from a given row ?

Example: I created a webpage for a small business that they can input all the details from a sale. That populates a google spreadsheet. Now I need to create a nice looking receipt (document) that includes the information from some of the fields in a particular row of that google spreadsheet to print out and give to the costumer for them to sign

Comment: Pretty sure if you can put data in, you can pull data out! What, pray tell, have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: If this is your way of telling me to search before I ask I did and that's why I'm asking I don't have a clue where to start

Comment: I have tried searching for populate documents from spreadsheet but all I find is how to do the reverse

Comment: I believe this is a valid question. All we ask is you show you have put some effort into it. Maybe add a reference to a few resources you may think are useful but still have questions.

Comment: To be honest all I have is about two hours of dead end google searches the closest thing was on this site I can't remember exactly but it was basically the reverse of what I need to do this looked like the right place for this sort of question

Comment: But again, what have you tried? Show us some code, and maybe we can point out something dead simple (really, sometimes it's as simple as a misplaced semicolon that causes you days of grief, and an extra set of eyes is all that is needed to find it) that would help you move forward. Without that, however, it's like asking someone else to write the solution en totale for you, which is not the purpose of StackOverflow. Not trying to be a jerk, but with the 1000's of solutions out there for any one problem, we need more to go on than, "I couldn't find anything to help me."

Comment: As far as code I am so lost. my intentions is to prepare this document I can probably use google docs or word if need be (if that's the right way to go about this I don't know) and my goal is to have this document populate the pertinent fields with the data collected earlier say the document states the costumers name how do I get that data from my google spreadsheet in row "15 a" (example) and also where row "15 d" the address an place it in the corresponding location and so on

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not more prepared but I'm a total noob in this I was exited when I made a form populate a spreadsheet I was just wondering if the data collected could be used to create different documents like receipts , delivery orders, service orders but I have no idea where to start thanks for your valuable time trying to help me

Comment: I wil take any idea on how to get started at this point

Comment: Ok I don't think I have ever searched for something for so long this might be exactly what I need but I need to study it further I will report back.  http://www.youpd.org/autocrat

Answer (score 1):

I coded a simple java script library todo the same thing after hours of search. (Wish I started it right away) [Gsheet2json](http://rumal.github.com/Gsheet2json/)

Upto now it can get data from the spreadsheet as objects array or arrays of array and you can use any template you want to publish it(of cause using your own java script + html).